# 2010 Hyundai Accent starts but won't stay running

Tags: engine, hyundai, idle, accent

Car would stop running while driving it and wouldn't start after that; changed the alternator and now it will start but it doesn't stay running. It stalls every time I try to put it in gear to drive it.

Comment: Can you rev the engine freely while in neutral

Comment: Did you do the work, or did a shop? This is typical behavior for an engine with a large vacuum leak. Once load is applies, the engine dies. You may take a look to see if any this is amiss which should be connected to the intake manifold such as the brake booster hose.

Answer (score 1):

Is the check engine light on? A relatively common failure is the crank shaft position sensor which can cause the car to die while driving. As well as hard starting/No start. IIRC the alternator on a Hyundai 4 cylinder is typically on the exhaust side of the engine near the radiator. So it may be safe to assume that the vacuum hoses are untouched.